Error about dart's two-dimensional array?
void main() {
  int pid = 12;
  int data1 = [12][1];
  for (int i = 0; i < pid; i++) {
    data1[i][0] = 0; // This is wrong
  }
}

Error message: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'int'.Try defining the operator '[]'
// This is not wrong in other languages,Please help answer thank you.
//Why doesn't this expression work? How to write it correctly

FYI: int data1 = [12][1]; is equivalent to List<int> tempList = [12]; int data1 = tempList[1];.  That is, the [12] is a List literal with a single element (the int 12), and then the [1] uses List.operator [] to dereference the element with index 1 (which is the second element since Dart lists are indexed starting from 0).  The static analyzer doesn't notice the out-of-bounds access, but you would get an exception if you tried to run it.

BTW, I'm not familiar with any languages where what you wrote would work.  Perhaps you're thinking of C or C++ where you could declare a 2D matrix with int data1[12][1];.

Here is the code with correct syntax.
void main() {
  int pid = 12;
  List<List<int>> data1 = List.generate(pid, (_) => [0, 0]); // Initialize a 2D list

  for (int i = 0; i < pid; i++) {
    data1[i][0] = 0; // Assign 0 to the first element of each sublist
  }
}


